# Javafx CSS values in code

Tags: javafx, fxml

Simply put, I have a JavaFX Textfield that I wish to 1) change the text color on, and 2) change it back to **that specified in CSS**. Does anyone know how to (generally) access css colors etc. from within the JavaFX code?

Comment: Have you tried to search the site?

Comment: Why do you need to access the css colors in code? Those are the styles that are used by default, so just remove any other styles you have applied.

Comment: Thanks James_D, guess I was looking for a java solution to a Javafx problem! setStyle(null) looks like it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
AnyFxElement.setStyle(String elementCss);
```

For source of all the css capabilities I reccomend looking up caspian css.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a style use the code:

```
    // remove the background color on the button
    yourElement.setStyle(null);
```

To set it back to it's default style:

```
    // set the button style back to the default class
    yourElement.setStyle(".yourStyle");
```